# How do I properly embed documents in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```javascript
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', new Schema({
    title     : String,
    body      : String,
    date      : Date
}))

var Post = mongoose.model('Post', new Schema({
    comments  : [Comment]
}))

module.exports.Comment = Comment
module.exports.Post = Post
```

Followed a tutorial for a simple app, and while trying to create something else off of it and learning about Mongoose schemas I get an error trying to use embedded documents with the way the previous app defined models

I'm getting this error

> throw new TypeError('Undefined type `' + name + '` at array `' + path
> +

TypeError: Undefined type `model` at array `comments`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To embed a document you need to pass its schema in the referencing document. For that, you can separately store the schema in variable as an intermediate step and later use it to define model.

```javascript
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var CommentSchema = new Schema({
    title     : String,
    body      : String,
    date      : Date
});

var PostSchema = new Schema({
    comments  : [CommentSchema]
});


module.exports.Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
module.exports.Post = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

Comment: I'm getting this

        throw new TypeError('Undefined type `' + name + '` at array `' + path +
        ^

TypeError: Undefined type `model` at array `comments`

Comment: but isn't that for just ref? I'm trying to do embedded documents

Comment: No, that is not for referencing a document. And the answer shows how you can embed an array of comments. If instead, you want to embed a single comment you can instead use `comments: CommentSchema`. For details on how to reference a document you can see more on https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html